# How to get Access Token and Access Token Secret for Magento?

Tags: rest, magento

I need to get the REST API from magento. I tried many ways but these are not working for me.
Already I got the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret and Oauth token and oauth_verifier but I don't know how to get access Token.

I mentioned the ways are I am getting the oauth token and oauth verifier but I can't get Access Token.

1.Getting an Unauthorized Request Token

```
URI localhost/magento/oauth/initiate

Method: POST

Return: Sample Response:
 oauth_token=xxqw0r7vo0xxxxxxxxx2sqj3vxwr0h&oauth_token_secret=xxg3x3jxxxxxxxxubjwyf9f1l21itrr&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

2.User Authorization

```
Uri: localhost/magento/oauth/authorize

Method: Get

Sample Response: /callback?oauth_token=xxxxxxx3lagl3o95xnox9xxxxxxpt3&oauth_verifier=xxxxxxlr5huizxxx6wi4l21zf05eb0
```

now I have Consumer Key , Secret Key, oAuth Token,oAuth verifier 
In step 3 I use

```
Uri: localhost/magento/oauth/token

Method: POST
```

but I cannot get Access Token. This URL shows oauth_problem=signature_invalid

Comment: Please show the ways that you tried.

Comment: @Enigmativity I given the way of I am tried.